# discontinuity of a function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

How do I show that

$$f( x,y) =\begin{cases} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x ^2 + y^2}} &   x^2+y^ 2\neq 0\\ 1 & x=y=0 \end{cases}$$

is discontinuous in $P(0,0)$
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's often useful to switch to polar coordinates, $x = r \cos\theta$ and $y = r \sin\theta.$ With these the function becomes
$$f_{\text{polar}}(r, \theta) = f(r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta) =
\begin{cases}
\cos\theta & \text{if $r\neq 0$} \\
1 & \text{if $r=0$}
\end{cases}$$

We see directly that $\lim_{0\neq r \to 0} f_{\text{polar}}(r, \theta)$ does not exist. Thus $f$ cannot be continuous at $0.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What's the limit of $f(0, y)$ as $y \to 0$? What about the limit of $f(x, 0)$ as $x \to 0$?

Comment: they both go to 0,but by definition of my function if x=y=0 f(0,0)=1, hence the limits are not equal and therefore my function is  discontinuous right?

Comment: They do not both go to zero. If they did, then the fact that the limit is $0$ but the value is $1$ would make the function discontinuous, (To be continuous at $(0,0)$, you must have $lim_{t \to 0} f(ta, tb) = f(0,0)$ for any numbers $a, b$, In fact you need more than that, but that is often a sufficient condition to check that something is NOT continuous at the origin).

Comment: right for f(x,0) x->0 its o/o thus undefined, i tried it with ur example by using the sequences 1/n for a and b and than got that the limit is unequal to 1 but i admit im not sure if im finished with this

Comment: No, that's not right either. I'm going to suggest you review limits for a little while.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a particular path: 
For $\phi: s\in (0,+\infty)\mapsto   (0,s)$ you have $f (\phi (s))=0$ identically and 0 is different from the value in $(0,0) $.